# Gwt Junit test HttpServletRequest Nullpointer

Tags: java, gwt, junit

I'm doing this project with GWT and when i make the Junit test for the LogIn method i get a NullPointerException because i check the session with HttpServletRequest.

Here the Junit test

```
private void checkLoginTest() {

    UsersServiceImpl USI = new UsersServiceImpl();

    UserDTO userDTO1 = new UserDTO();
    UserDTO userDTO2 = new UserDTO();

    User user1 = new User("username1", "password1", "email1",
            "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", UserRights.USER);
    User user2 = new User("username2", "password2", "email2",
            "aa", "aa", "aa", "aa", UserRights.USER);

    userDTO1.setUser(user1);
    userDTO2.setUser(user2);

    UserDTO insertedUser1 = USI.register(userDTO1);
    UserDTO insertedUser2 = USI.register(userDTO2);

    /* 
     * Check login success
     */
    Assert.assertNotNull(USI.checkLogin("username1", "password1"));
    Assert.assertNotNull(USI.checkLogin("username2", "password2"));
    //Wrong password below
    Assert.assertNull(USI.checkLogin("username2", "ciaone"));

    /*
     * Check user returned by login
     */
    /*Assert.assertEquals(user1.getUsername(), USI.checkLogin("username1", "password1"));
    Assert.assertEquals(user2.getUsername(), USI.checkLogin("username2", "password2"));*/
}
```

And here the method checkLogin from UsersServiceImpl

```
public UserDTO checkLogin(String username, String password) {

    // boolean check = false;
    UserDTO checkedUser = new UserDTO();

    mapDB.begin();

    Map<String, User> userMap = mapDB.getDB().createTreeMap("UserMap")
            .makeOrGet();

    if (userMap.containsKey(username)) {
        // Controllo se la password è corretta per quello username
        checkedUser.setUser(userMap.get(username));

        if (checkedUser.getUser().getPassword().equals(password)) {
            // check = true;
            checkedUser.setLogged(true);
            // Salvo la sessione utente
            storeUserInSession(checkedUser);
        } else {

            checkedUser.setUser(null);
        }

    } else {

        checkedUser.setUser(null);
    }

    mapDB.end();

    return checkedUser;
}

private void storeUserInSession(UserDTO user) {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
    HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
}
```

The storeUserInSession return null and i get the NullPointerException.

How can i avoid this, or how can i call an HttpServletRequest for session in Junit test?

Ok changed the method storeUserInSession with

```
private void storeUserInSession(UserDTO user) {
    //Junit test ritorna NullPointerException 
    //In questo modo funziona
    try {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
        HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("user", user);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Errore creazione HttpServeletRequest");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Or can be good this one too

```
private void storeUserInSession(UserDTO user) {

        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = this.getThreadLocalRequest();
        if( httpServletRequest != null){
          HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession(true);
          session.setAttribute("user", user);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There different solutions to your problem:

1. You could change the test to become a GWT Testcase, this would be run in the browser as compiled JavaScript.
2. You could change the visibility of `storeUserInSession` to `protected`, derive from that `Class` and change the method for your test.
3. You could use a mocking framework like "Powermockito" to mock the Session
4. You could make `storeUserInSession` NullPointer safe and return true or false, if the data was stored.

I would use way 1 or 4, because this would be the easiest ways.

The most elegant way is 3, I think, but you would need to learn a mocking framework.

Comment: I agree with your choice, 1 and 4.
It's a university project i don't know if i can use method 3!

I will try method 1 and 4, and when it works i will check your answer...if i get some problem keep posting here or open another question? (what do you think?)

Comment: Edited with the solution! Thanks for the support!